# (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v2): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Exception Description:

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, wildfly, connector

I'm facing this error whit my EAR projec: This ear have 4 modules (EJB-standard-2 web modules)

I'm not using MAVEN. Server is Wildfly17.0.1 final

I'v already put connector in every web-inf\lib folder

also put connector in wildfly17.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main and created the module.xml

```
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.12" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

I also tried to deploy connector within wildfly console but nothing worked so far.

I also tried with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   
   <persistence-unit name="jpaServer" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
//various classes
      <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/progettoestateserver"/><!-- da cambiare -->
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
       <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

dunno what to do, everytime it seems a pretty simple solution to put connector jar into projects folder but it dosen't work

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at ejb_connessioni.ConnessioniEJB.apriconnessione(ConnessioniEJB.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:185)
    ... 166 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.configurationErrorClassNotFound(DatabaseException.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.loadDriverClass(DefaultConnector.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    ... 202 more
```

Comment: Your title does not agree with the error message in your post.

Comment: Have you actually added the driver in the standalone.xml?

Comment: Yes, i did 
```<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
 <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
 <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>```

But still facing the error

it still using h2
```INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)```

Comment: I switch to JNDI in order to let "him" use the connector, and atleast the database is auto generated correctly, but still facind the error when i'm gonna put an entry

Comment: AFAIK, `<resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.12" />` should be `<resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar" />`